# Reverse look up on user id

Tags: python

So I'm using a dict() within a dict() with multiple keys. One of the keys is an ID number. I am trying to make a reverse look up to use the ID that matches with the corresponding user that has that ID and return the user. But I haven't really figure out how to. I was thinking this:

```
users = {"jim": {"id": 1, "rank": [1, "chaz", 12], "points": 233}, "bill": {"id": 14, "rank": [2, "franklin", 14], "points": 455}}

def reverse_lookup(id_num, d=users):
    try:
        id_num = id_num.replace("#", "")
        for user in d:
            if d[user]["id"] == id_num:
                return user
    except Exception as e: return "Error: %s" % e

print(reverse_lookup("#14"))

returns None
```

Would this code be correct and functional? because I really doubt that it will work.

Comment: Why don't you just try it instead of making us guess as to whether it'll work or not

Comment: You're trying to `raise` an error from *inside* a `try`, which is... interesting. You also compare an integer to a list; that'll never be `True`. Also, your handling of the dictionary is frankly bizarre. But @sshashank124 is right; you should be running this yourself, reading the error messages and trying to fix it yourself before you dump it on us.

Comment: Because I have uncertainties and I really doubt I could figure it out without a little help.

Comment: @user3230748 you "doubt it"? Why not *try* and find out?! You will certainly never get anywhere if you don't learn to [debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Well I tryed out a different way and I'll post it but it returns None instead of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this and compare it with yours:

```
def reverse_id_lookup(id_code, users):
    id_code = int(id_code.split("#", 1)[1])
    for user, info in users.items():
        if info['id'] == id_code:
            return user
    else:
        raise Exception("ID does not exist yet.")
```